# How can sort data datewise in Appmekar?

Tags: google-app-maker

In Google Appmekar i need to sort data in datewise so i used below line but didn't work.

```
    myDataSource1.query.sorting.inwarddate._ascending();
```

anyone have idea about appmekar?

Answer (score 0):

That should work, except that each time you want to sort the datasource, you have to load it. Hence, it should look like this:

```
myDatasource1.query.sorting.inwarddate._ascending();
myDatasource1.load();
```

You should take a look at the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#Query) for more details.